# How to properly switch between sqlite core data files?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

So I am currently experiencing some troubles between switching between coredata files. The scenario is as follows:

1) There are two users authorized to use my app, and each user has their own sqlite file to represent their own data due to a need for separation of concerns
2) When User A logs out and User B logs in... core data should switch to User B's sqlite file and live within that file only.

If I remove User A's PSC and create a new one for User B, am I in the safe zone or am I missing more steps? I am noticing some data from User A ends up in User B's core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to switch between persistent store files and you can't have data from one connect to data from the other, you need to tear down the entire Core Data stack and then re-create it. That means:

- All `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`s
- All `NSManagedObjectContext`s
- All managed objects that you have loaded from Core Data, anywhere in your app

Each of these needs to be replaced with a new instance, exactly as you would do when the app first launches. Because of this, it's sometimes best to also tear down the entire UI, reloading everything from the initial view controller.

If you've copied data from managed objects to other places (other properties or UI elements) you need to make sure to get rid of that as well.

The `NSManagedObjectModel` can stay, because it never holds any data from a persistent store.

Comment: I've rechecked my code and I confirmed that after I removed the PSC, I set the psc variable to nil, and I also set the managedObjectContext to nil as well. Is that sufficient in regards to tearing it down, or are you suggesting I dealloc the memory location?

Comment: If you're using ARC, "dealloc" doesn't make sense. You DO need to also be absolutely sure to get rid of every managed object, everywhere in the app.

Comment: Are you recommending I use deleteObject: on my context for every entity type? How would that affect User A if User B triggers the save: function during usage of the app?

Comment: No, I am not recommending that you delete data. I'm saying that you must be sure that no managed object is in memory, anywhere.

Comment: Alrighty, let me take a stab at this again. I appreciate your help Tom.